# how to receive an entity with image from requestParam

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to save an entity (Product) with many attributes, one of them , the picture. And I don't know how to get both (entity and image) in the controller.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody Product product,
BindingResult result, @RequestParam("imageData") MultipartFile imageData);
```

If i put it this way I get an "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------889210147211052471233495;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]" error.

If I only get the @RequestParam, because I suppose, I cannot use two both Request at the same time, I don't know how to send both, product and image.
And much less, I don't know yet how to send this information from the front-end in react.

```
export const ProductForm = ({ productSelected }) => {

const initialProductForm = {
    id: 0,
    productName: '',
    description: '',
    image: " ",
    price: 0,
}

    const { initialProductForm, handlerAddProduct, errors } = useProducts();

    const [productForm, setProductForm] = useState(initialProductForm);
    let { id, productName, description, image, price } = productForm;

    const onInputChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target;
        setProductForm({
            ...productForm,
            [name]: value,
        })
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
 
        imageData.append('product',productForm);
        imageData.append('imageName', imageName);
        imageData.append('imageData', imageData);
        handlerAddProduct(productForm);
    }

    const handleChange = event => {
        setImageName(event.target.value)
    };

    const [imageData, setImageData] = useState(null);
    const [imageName, setImageName] = useState("");

return (
        <>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST" encType="application/json">
                <input
                    className="form-control my-3 w-75"
                    placeholder="ProductName"
                    name="productName"
                    value={productName}
                    onChange={onInputChange}
                />
                <p className="text-danger">{errors?.productName}</p>

                <input type="number"
                    className="form-control my-3 w-75"
                    placeholder="Price"
                    name="price"
                    value={price}
                    onChange={onInputChange}
                />
                <p className="text-danger">{errors?.price}</p>

                <input
                    className="form-control my-3 w-75"
                    placeholder="Description"
                    name="description"
                    value={description}
                    onChange={onInputChange}
                />
                <p className="text-danger">{errors?.description}</p>


                <input
                    accept="image/*"                 
                    id="upload-profile-image"
                    name="image"
                    type="file"                  

                    onChange={handleUploadClick}
                />

                <label htmlFor="upload-profile-image">
                    <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        component="span"
                    >
                        Change Image
                    </Button>
                </label>

                <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    label="Image Name"
                    margin="dense"
                    name="name"      
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    required
                    value={imageName}
                    variant="outlined"
                />

                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="id"
                    value={id}
                />

                <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    type="submit">
                    {id > 0 ? 'Update' : 'Create'}
                </button>

            </form>
        </>
    )

}
```

ProductService:

```
export const save = async (product) => {



    try {

        return await usersApi.post(`${BASE_URL}/products/addProduct`, product, imageData);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("errrooorrr " + error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

I can't make the controller work even from Postman. [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuVIs.png)

And of course I'm complete lost from React Front-end.

Please. Help :)

Thanks a lot.

To get the product and the image to do this: product.setImage()= image.getBytes();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure if it's possible to receive JSON RequestBody and image/file in same request. But you can try approaches below

1. Convert image to base64 string and add it to json request. This way you will be able to receive request as RequestBody from which you can read base64 image data and convert it to image.

Eg.

Request

```
 {
    "productName" : "Xbox",
    "description"  : "Xbox",
    "price" : "500",
    "imageData" : "image base64 string data here"
   }
```

Receive request

```
@PostMapping("/json")
public void readJsonRequest(@RequestBody(required = true) String jsonRequest) {

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonRequest);
    String productName = object.getString("productName");
    String imageData = object.getString("imageData");
        
    //convert imageData from base64 to image
}
```

2. Send request as ContentType: multipart/form-data. This way you can add keys and receive them using RequestParams & MultipartFile

E.g
Request

```
    Key                     value
    
    productName             Xbox
    description             Xbox
    price                   500
    imageFile               selected file (.png, .jpg etc)
```

Receive request

```
 @PostMapping("/request")
 public void readRequest(@RequestParam(value = "productName", required = true) String productName,
            @RequestParam(value = "description", required = true) String description,
        @RequestParam(value = "price", required = true) String price,
            @RequestParam(value = "imageFile", required = true) MultipartFile imageFile) {

 }
```

To send Json object as entity, ensure keys/properties in json request matches fields names in your entity class. Eg `productName` key in json request should match `private String productName` in Product entity class.

To receive it

```
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody Product product,
            BindingResult result) {

}
```

Comment: Hi. It worked!!!. The problem is that in that way I can have the data of the product, but I cannot make the validation from the Entity with BindingResult as I was doing before with public ResponseEntity<?> createWithFoto(@Valid @RequestBody Product product, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile image)    because the error message was Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryeRhHAnjcLSlAa8rX;charset=UTF-8' is not supported].

Comment: By the way, How would it be the correct way??? Please :)

Comment: I've added to the answer how you can send and receive json object as entity

Comment: I haven't tried this. If you still need to send json object and image file in same request you can try this https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/07/27/requestbody-and-multipart-on-spring-boot/#:~:text=To%20pass%20the%20Json%20and,type%20in%20the%20consume%20part.&text=And%20we%20need%20to%20pass,%2B%20file%20not%20POJO%20%2B%20file.&text=Then%20convert%20the%20String%20to%20Json%20using%20ObjectMapper%20in%20Service%20layer.