# How to use retrofit with @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, retrofit2

I have the below method signature:

`public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@Valid @ModelAttribute FileDetails fileDetails)`

The FileDetails class:

```
@Builder
@Data
public class FileDetails {
  private String filename;
  private String folderName;
  private MultipartFile file;
}
```

Now I want to use retrofit on `uploadFile` in another service. But it's giving error. The ways i have tried are like:

```
Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile(@ModelAtrribute FileDetails fileDetails)
```

gives `No retrofit annotation found`

even if i remove the @ModelAttribute it's giving the same error.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76655712/how-to-receive-an-entity-with-image-from-requestparam/76677954#76677954) might help you to upload files