# Uploading Multiple Pictures using vanilla Javasript and Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a multipart file request that sends multiple pictures to a spring boot endpoint. below it is the controller endpoint:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadPropertyPictures(@RequestParam MultipartFile [] files, @RequestParam String propCode) throws IOException{
        
        return ResponseEntity.status(200).body(service.savePropertyPicturesToDatabase(files, propCode));
}
```

However, I am sending the following request in JavaScript

```
pictureFormData.append('files', files)
pictureFormData.append('propCode', newProperty.propCode);
    
await fetch(new URL("http://localhost:8083/property/upload"), {
        
   method: "POST",
   body:pictureFormData
})
.then((response) => {

   response.text();
})
.catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

After sending this request, I am getting an error 400, and it says, 'the request part 'files' is not present'. ~ Please see attached pictures. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[Error 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNSr0.png)

[Request Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqjuu.png)

I tried multiple ways in uploading the files using different annotations such as @RequestPart, @RequestParam in the back-end. I also tried using XMLHttpRequest. Did some research, but to no avail. I lack understanding in front end, so I would need help. thank you

Comment: Check out this on [how to upload files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76655712/how-to-receive-an-entity-with-image-from-requestparam/76677954#76677954)

Comment: Thanks Eric for the link