# Uploading and Displaying Images in Angular with Spring Boot, and Retrieving from Database

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I'm working on a project where I need to implement a feature that allows users to upload images using an Angular frontend. Let's say Person is my Entity , i have already created UI for taking user input including Image of person.
How to save image so that later on i can retrieve it from database and display in webpage using angular and spring boot ?

I did some research but i was not able to get it. Is there anyone who can teach me to do so ?

Comment: You should provide some code, what you've already tried to do. Otherwise this question will likely get closed.

Comment: I haven't found any code, to try with. so i am here asking for help

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76655712/how-to-receive-an-entity-with-image-from-requestparam/76677954#76677954) to upload using postman. Though OP was uploading using React, concept should be the same even for Angular