# Test Spring Boot Multipart API End Point using Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, multipart, http-request-parameters

I am trying to build an api end point to receive formdata along with Image file.  I have a Spring Boot end point shown below:

```
    @PostMapping("/user/personUpload")
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResposeModel> personUploadWithImage(@RequestParam("person") PersonModel person, @RequestParam("personImage")   MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
.................
             
    }
~~
How do I test this from postman. I always get 404 resource not found error.

[!This is the screenshot of Postman for testing the end point.][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjgGH.png
```

Comment: If you are encountering a 404 error when testing your Spring Boot multipart API endpoint using Postman, it indicates that Postman cannot find the resource at the specified URL. Ensure that the URL you're using in Postman matches the endpoint mapping in your Spring Boot application. If your Spring Boot application has a base path or context path configured, make sure you include it in the URL. Also, make sure your Postman request is correctly configured to send the data as multipart/form-data and that the field names (person and personImage) match the @RequestParam names in controller method.

Comment: You can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76655712/how-to-receive-an-entity-with-image-from-requestparam/76677954#76677954)

Comment: Thanjks .  My problem is solved I has an error in matching url with end point.  But I have another issue which I will raise  separately.