# SpringBoot/Thymeleaf MultipartFile not Binding to ModelAttribute Class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to use SpringBoot and Thymeleaf to upload a file along with two other fields in a form using the @ModelAttribute annotation. When I hit the /create POST endpoint, I get a Java exception saying "Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile.getName()" because the return value of "pro.sammyg7241.easyexchange.entities.UploadRequest.getFile()" is null".

Page Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title th:text="${appTitle} + ' | Upload Document'"></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link th:replace="~{fragments/dependencies.html}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:replace="~{fragments/public_navigation.html}"></div>
        <h2>Upload Document</h2>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:if="${errorMsg.length() > 0}"></div>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" th:if="${uploadSuccess}">File uploaded successfully.</div>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/upload}" th:object="${uploadReq}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sessionGuid">Upload Session GUID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="sessionGuid" class="form-control" placeholder="Upload Session GUID" th:field="*{sessionGUID}" th:value="${uploadReq.getSessionGUID()}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="clientEmail">Client Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="clientEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Client Email" th:field="*{clientEmail}" th:value="${uploadReq.getClientEmail()}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="file">Attach File:</label>
                <input type="file" id="file" value="file" class="form-control-file" th:field="*{file}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller Methods:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/upload")
   public String getUpload(Model model)
   {
      model.addAttribute("appTitle", title);
      model.addAttribute("uploadReq", new UploadRequest());
      model.addAttribute("errorMsg", "");
      model.addAttribute("uploadSuccess", false);
      return "upload";
   }

   @PostMapping(value = "/upload")
   public String postUpload(@ModelAttribute UploadRequest req, ModelMap model) throws IOException
   {
      //Upload document to S3
      S3Helper s3 = new S3Helper(accessKey, secretKey, region, bucketName);
      s3.uploadSessionFile(req.getSessionGUID(), req.getFile().getName(), req.getFile().getBytes());

      //Build document object
      Document newDoc = new Document();
      newDoc.setGuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      newDoc.setFileName(req.getFile().getName());
      newDoc.setFileType(req.getFile().getContentType());
      newDoc.setUploadedAt(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm").format(new Date()));
      newDoc.setDownloadNonce(s3.generateDownloadNonce());
      docRepo.save(newDoc);

      model.addAttribute("appTitle", title);
      model.addAttribute("uploadReq", req);
      model.addAttribute("errorMsg", "");
      model.addAttribute("uploadSuccess", true);
      return "upload";
   }
```

UploadRequest Class:

```
public class UploadRequest
{
   private String sessionGUID;
   private String clientEmail;
   private MultipartFile file;

   public String getSessionGUID()
   {
      return sessionGUID;
   }

   public void setSessionGUID(String sessionGUID)
   {
      this.sessionGUID = sessionGUID;
   }

   public String getClientEmail()
   {
      return clientEmail;
   }

   public void setClientEmail(String clientEmail)
   {
      this.clientEmail = clientEmail;
   }

   public MultipartFile getFile()
   {
      return file;
   }

   public void setFile(MultipartFile file)
   {
      this.file = file;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can upload file & data [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76655712/how-to-receive-an-entity-with-image-from-requestparam/76677954#76677954)